# Entity Framework 6.1.3 Hierarchy id not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, hierarchy

I am trying to use SQL server HierarchyId data type with Entity Framework. Since entity framework doesn't have support for HierarchyId data type I am using Entity Framework fork which has hierarchyid support:
https://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/network/forks/zgabi/EfHierarchyId/latest

DB Table is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE OrgStructure(
    [Id] [hierarchyid] NOT NULL,
    [Level]  AS ([Id].[GetLevel]()),
    [NodeId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Title] [varchar](50) NULL)
```

My Entity which uses HierarchyId data type is defined follows:

```
public class OrgStructure
{        
    public HierarchyId  Id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Level { get; set; }
    public int NodeId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

and EntityFramework Mapping configuration is defined as:

```
public class OrgStructureMapping: EntityTypeConfiguration<OrgStructure>
{
    public OrgStructureMapping()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.Id);

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.Id)
            .HasColumnType("hierarchyId")
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed);

        this.Property(t => t.NodeId)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        this.Property(t => t.Title)
            .HasMaxLength(50);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("OrgStructure");
        this.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
        this.Property(t => t.Level).HasColumnName("Level");
        this.Property(t => t.NodeId).HasColumnName("NodeId");
        this.Property(t => t.Title).HasColumnName("Title");
    }
}
```

DBContext is as follows:

```
public partial class VisibilityHierarchyDBContext : DbContext
{

    public virtual DbSet<OrgStructure> OrgStructure { get; set; }

    public VisibilityHierarchyDBContext(string nameOrConnectionString)
    : base(nameOrConnectionString)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new OrgStructureMapping());            
    }
}
```

Registered DbContext in startup.cs as follows

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddScoped<VisibilityHierarchyDBContext>((s) => new VisibilityHierarchyDBContext(Configuration.GetConnectionString("VisibilityDB")));

        // Add framework services.
        services.AddMvc();
    }
```

Using DBContext as follows:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    VisibilityHierarchyDBContext context;
    public HomeController(VisibilityHierarchyDBContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var o = context.OrgStructure.Take(5).ToList();  /* Exception is  thrown here */

        return View();
    }
 }
```

I am getting following error in Index action shown above:

> The 'Id' property on 'OrgStructure' could not be set to a
>   'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlHierarchyId' value. You must set this
>   property to a non-null value of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Hierarchy.HierarchyId'.

Any help to resolve this error is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you share example of how are you adding new rows to `OrgStructure` table?

Comment: @nocodename : I have manually populated table and just trying to retrieve existing data using DbContext.

Comment: Something I've just noticed - should `Id` property be set as `IsOptional()` ? Have you tried map it as required with `Computed` DatabaseGeneratedOption?

Comment: @nocodename: Sorry IsOptional() was there by mistake. I was trying something else. Updated question.

Comment: Can you provide me with your code to get data?

Comment: @nocodename: Updated question with required details.

Comment: Have you tried skipping `Take()` method? Maybe fork doesn't implement it? One way or another, I don't have any other idea of how to help you :( I suggest addressing the question to the fork author. Sorry :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Actually error message is bit misleading. When I removed "Level" property from entity definition and mapping it worked like charm. It was breaking because Level column is defined as computed column which auto picks smallint as datatype whereas in entity definition its type is int.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using using `Computed` as the `DatabaseGeneratedOption` instead of `None`?

Comment: Tried setting it to Computed but didn't help.